# How can i create/add a balloon tooltip to each array item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] arr = new string[4];
            ListViewItem itm;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                arr[0] = "Ready";
                arr[1] = "";
                arr[2] = Properties.Settings.Default.AddNewDownloadsUrl;
                arr[3] = Properties.Settings.Default.AddNewDownloadsSaveto;
                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                listView1.Items.Add(itm);
                links.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.AddNewDownloadsUrl);
                ListViewExtended.ListViewHelper.colorReady(listView1, Color.Red);
            }
        }
```

I want that when the user will move the mouse cursor over one of the arr's it will show a text on it. For example on arr[3] when the user move the mouse cursor over it in the listView show the Properties.Settings.Default.AddNewDownloadsSaveto text. AddNewDownloadsSaveto is a string.

Comment: The built-in ListView does not provide per-cell tooltips.  You would need to do your own hit testing and manually trigger a tooltip to be displayed/hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using `ListView`'s `HitTest` method. That method checks, using current mouse location, if pointer is over (sub)item. To use it with `ToolTip`, you can do something like this (on my test form, I have `ListView` named `listView1` and `ToolTip` named `toolTip1`):

- subscribe to `ListView`'s `MouseMove` and `MouseLeave` events
- on `MouseMove` check if pointer is over `SubItem`. If it is, take subitem's text and show `ToolTip`.
- hide `ToolTip` when pointer leaves `ListView`

see test code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //subscribe to events - when mouse leaves listview and when mouse is moved over listview
    listView1.MouseLeave += ListView1_MouseLeave;
    listView1.MouseMove += ListView1_MouseMove;
}

private void ListView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //using current location, check what is under mouse
    var info = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);

    //if any subitem is selected
    if (info.SubItem != null)
    {

        //set tooltip's new location to the bottom right of mouse pointer
        Point calculatedLocation = new Point(e.X + 20, e.Y + 20);
        //show tooltip - with subitem text, on this window, on calculated location and hold it there for 3 seconds.
        toolTip1.Show(info.SubItem.Text, listView1, calculatedLocation, 3000);
    }
}

private void ListView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //hide tooltip
    this.toolTip1.Hide(this);
}
```

Unfortunately, `ToolTip` will flicker, due to constant redrawal when user moves mouse. To (try) to avoid that, you can have variable holding reference to `ListViewSubItem` on which pointer is currently located. When mouse comes over `ListViewSubItem` show `ToolTip`, but while pointer is moving over it, don't redraw. When user moves onto another `ListViewSubItem`, show/draw `ToolTip` again. That can be achieved like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //variable for "remembering" subItem on which tooltip is shown
    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem selectedListViewSubItem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    } 

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //subscribe to events - when mouse leaves listview and when mouse is moved over listview
        listView1.MouseLeave += ListView1_MouseLeave;
        listView1.MouseMove += ListView1_MouseMove;

    }

    private void ListView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //using current location, check what is under mouse
        var info = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);

        //if any subitem is selected AND subitem differs from last one
        if (info.SubItem != null  && info.SubItem != selectedListViewSubItem)
        {
            //remember current subitem
            selectedListViewSubItem = info.SubItem;
            //set tooltip's new location to the bottom right of mouse pointer
            Point calculatedLocation = new Point(e.X + 20, e.Y + 20);
            //show tooltip - with subitem text, on this window, on calculated location and hold it there for 3 seconds.
            toolTip1.Show(info.SubItem.Text, listView1, calculatedLocation, 3000);
        }
    }

    private void ListView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //hide tooltip
        this.toolTip1.Hide(this);
    }
```

But, when used like this, `ToolTip` won't move with mouse pointer. :)
I hope I gave you an idea how to solve your problem.  If you have additional questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfect for me

Created two events: listView1_MouseMove and Form1_MouseMove

```
    ToolTip mTooltip;
    Point mLastPos = new Point(-1, -1);
    ListViewHitTestInfo info;
    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lastSubItem;

    private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        info = listView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        if (mTooltip == null)
            mTooltip = new ToolTip();

        if (mLastPos != e.Location)
        {
            if (info.Item != null && info.SubItem != null)
            {
                if (info.SubItem != lastSubItem)
                {
                    mTooltip.ToolTipTitle = info.Item.Text;
                    mTooltip.Show(info.SubItem.Text, info.Item.ListView, e.X, e.Y, 20000);
                    lastSubItem = info.SubItem;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mTooltip.SetToolTip(listView1, string.Empty);
            }
        }

        mLastPos = e.Location;
    }
```

Form1:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1 != null)
        {
            if (!listView1.Bounds.Contains(e.X, e.Y) && mTooltip != null)
            {
                mTooltip.SetToolTip(listView1, "");
                lastSubItem = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: lol, you answered your own question a minute before I've added my answer :)

Comment: @Nino hehe just saw it now.